# Consulta sobre respuesta HTML

Tags: php, html, ajax, script, paypal

me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de enviar un **mail** a través de un `script` de **PayPal** con los datos ingresados. Es decir, los pongo en plano, tengo un `*index.html*` bastante simple en donde inserto el botón de `PayPal` para realizar la transacción:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Internos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Fede Pistone</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <label for="fname">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre...">
        <label for="lname">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido...">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email...">
        <label for="subject">Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Ingresa tu consulta..." style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <div id="smart-button-container">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p>Al presionar el botón, se abrirá un formulario en el cuál deberá abonar un monto de u$s20. <br>Recuerde que al presionarlo, usted está aceptando esto. <br>Una vez procesado el pago, recibirá un mail con un link para una reunión virtual con un horario específico. <br>Por favor, consulte en su bandeja de entrada y/o spam.</p>

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      function initPayPalButton() {
        paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',

          },

          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{"description":"Ejemplo de botón","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":20}}]
            });
          },

          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

              // Full available details
              console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

              // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
              const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
              element.innerHTML = '';
              element.innerHTML = '<h3>Gracias, nos estaremos comunicando contigo a la brevedad.</h3>';

              // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

            });
          },

          onError: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      }
      initPayPalButton();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como se observa, este `script` posee una `function onApprove`. Es ahí donde me gustaría saber, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al recibir esta respuesta se envíe un **mail**? Hice este archivo `php` para enviar el **mail**, el mismo funciona (ya hice pruebas independiente). Solo quisiera saber, cómo hago para que se envíe el **mail** una vez que recibí el estado `onApprove`:

**enviarmail.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["mensaje"]) ){
            $to = "francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Datos de formulario de contacto";
            $contenido .= "Nombre: ".$_POST["nombre"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Apellido: ".$_POST["apellido"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n\n";
            $contenido .= "Mensaje: ".$_POST["mensaje"]."\n\n";
            $header = "From: francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com\nReply-To:".$_POST["email"]."\n";
            $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            if(mail($to, $subject, $contenido ,$header)){
                echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
            }else{
                echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);
            }
            exit;
    }
?>
```

**Update:**

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
        var nombreJunto = nombre + " " + apellido;
        var mailForm = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var mensajeForm = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

        // Full available details
        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

        // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
        const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'enviarmail.php',
          dataType: "json",
          data:{nombre:nombreJunto, email:mailForm, mensaje:mensajeForm},
          success: function(response) {
              alert(response.success);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
              console.log(xhr);
            }
          });

        if (document.referrer !== document.location.href) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.location.reload()
          }, 5000);
        }

        // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

      });
    },
```

Comment: Estás usando mail() sin pasarle parámetros, así claro que no te va a funcionar. Y deberías hacer algo distinto cuando mail() falla, ¿qué te parece recoger el error? https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: Ya lo hice pasándole los parámetro y también falla @JoséCarlosPHP

Comment: En el else de if(mail()) haz algo que te permita saber con certeza si PHP retornó éxito o no. En caso de que no (que así tiene pinta), entramos en problemas de correo desde PHP, que es un mundillo. Yo te recomendaría usar PHPMailer, podrás enviar como mail(), o por SMTP, obtener un mensaje claro en caso de error... https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Imprimo un true/false para controlar si el mail sale o no. Pues, imprime false el alert ya que no sale el mail :/ eso sí, cambié el php y el ajax para probar alternativas pero no funciona aún @JoséCarlosPHP

Comment: Pues eso, tienes el problema en el envío del correo, que es un mundillo. Yo te sigo recomendando usar PHPMailer. O, si tienes ganas de calentarte la cabeza, puedes aprender más sobre mail(), y los problemas que puede tener, contrastarlos con la situación en tu hosting/servidor, y actuar para solventarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la tecnica AJAX que envía parametros en formato json a cualquier lenguaje del lado del servidor, si lo cobinas con el plugin jquery te será mas fácil su uso te dejo un ejemplo.Ponerlo dentro de `onAprove`.

Sin jquery:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequets();
xmlhttp.open("POST","enviarmail.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
    element.innerHTML = '';
    element.innerHTML = '<h3>Gracias, nos estaremos comunicando contigo a la 
    brevedad. </h3>';
  }else{
         //Cualquier cosa.
  }
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('contact-form'));
  request.send(formData);
  xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Utilizando el pluggin jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"enviarmail.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:'e-mail', nombre:'el nombre', email:'el correo', mensaje:'el mensaje'},
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(response){
      if(response.status == 200){
        const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
          element.innerHTML = '';
          element.innerHTML = '<h3>Gracias, nos estaremos comunicando contigo a la 
          brevedad.</h3>';
      }else{
          //otra cosa.
      }
    }
 });
```

dentro del php, sustituye lo que esta dentro del `if` por la llamada a la función que recuerdo me la presto un amigo en un post que hice, y con ella retorna los datos como respuesta de la petición ajax, pon el código al principio del archivo.

```
//función jsonoutput()
function json_output($status = 200, $msg = 'OK', $data = null){
  header("Content-Type: aplication/json; charset=utf-8");
  echo json_encode([
    'status' => $status,
    'msg' => $msg,
    'data' => $data
  ]);
  die;
 }
 //luego como te explique la llamas dentro del if.
 json_output(estatus de la petición "200 o  400", mensaje, cualquier dato 
 a retornar);
//recuerda que los estring se pasan entre comillas "" o '',
```

Comment: hmm, pues no. Intente con el pluggin de jQuery pero no me ha funcionado. Ni siquiera cambia el texto del div del botón de paypal

Comment: cierto perdon se me olvidó poner que devias retornar una respuesta con `json_encode();`, ahora te edito la respuesta

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias

Comment: @Franqo Balsamo listo ya está editada espero te sirva cualquier duda escribeme

Comment: ¿A json_output() lo debo llamar dentro del if(mail())?

Comment: dentro de las llaves, `if(mail()){ json_output();}else{ json_output();}`

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con tus modificaciones, debido a que el `div` si cambia pero el mail nunca llega

Comment: Estás usando mail() sin pasarle parámetros. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Tu hosting tiene habilitada la función mail() ? Pudiste ver en el LOG si aparece algo al respecto?

Comment: El hosting tiene habilitada la función de mail porque sin usar ajax, el mail se envía @AleBuo

Comment: @Franqo Balsamo bro. ya he revisado tu código y la verdad está bastante bien, así que para saber el problema hagamos un poco de depuración; la función `mail()` retorna `true/false` dependiendo de si logró o no enviar el mensaje así que haremos lo siguente.

Comment: Metemos `mail()` en una variable `$mensaje = mail('los parametros que vas a enviar');`  y con el `if` comprobaremos `if($mensaje === true){ retorna que si }else{ retorna que no}` y luego me dices.

Comment: EN la actualización que hice, el alert me devuelve el false

Comment: ok por favor pasa la publicaci'ion a un chat para estar más cómodos y cuando encontremos la solución arreglamos la publicación.

Comment: El `false` que retorna te dice que no se está enviando el mensaje, tienes que revisar que no se está pasando mal algún parámetro a la función, o si está conectando bien con  el servidor al que está enviando el mensaje. prueba enviandole al archivo `php` un formulario común, a ver que respuesta te retorna.

Comment: ya encontré mi error, muchas gracias por tu ayuda genio

Comment: no es nada, ni genio ni nada solo paso horas haciendo depuración. ;-)